# Applying lpSolveAPI

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, lpsolve

I have a number of variables denoting equipment I can replace. When replaced, they improve an impact metric, `[I]`. Each also has an associated annual cost savings `[S]` and replacement cost `[C]`.

```
n <- 1000 # variable count

# impact
# negative for use in minimization function
I <- -rnorm(n, mean=20000, sd=8000)
# cost savings
s <- rnorm(n, mean=2500, sd=1000)
# replacement cost
c <- rnorm(n, mean=15000, sd=5000)
```

I want to select which components to replace to maximize the impact across the board within a budget, while still making sure the entire project (as a whole) has meets a simple payback goal.

```
payback_goal <- 3
budget <- 1000000
```

This problem is described by the equations below.

[image]

I'm struggling to set this up with `lpSolveAPI`. Specifically, I don't know how to incorporate Eq. 3.

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
m <- 2 # number of constraints, disregarding binary constraint set by type
my.lp <- make.lp(m, n)
set.row(my.lp, 1, c)
# i don't think this is the correct way to set up the calculation
set.row(my.lp, 2, c/s) # cost divided by savings

# create obj fn coefficients
set.objfn(my.lp, I)
set.type(my.lp, 1:n, "binary")

eq <- c("<=", "<=")
set.constr.type(my.lp, eq)
set.rhs(my.lp, c(budget, payback_goal))

solve(my.lp)
soln1 <- get.variables(my.lp)

# total cost
s1_cost <- sum(soln1 * c)
# total impact
s1_impact <- -get.objective(my.lp)
# total simple payback
s1_pb <- sum(soln1*c) / sum(soln1*s)
```

I've tried a somewhat hacky workaround, that assumes the total cost will be reasonably close to the budget, which makes the third equation

[image]

But this is just an approximation and I'd like to know how to implement it more exactly within the R code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can linearize (3) as follows, using your notation:

```
 sum([X]*[C]) - payback*sum([X]*[S]) <= 0
```

That can be rewritten as;

```
 sum([X]*([C]-payback*[S])) <= 0
```

This is valid as long as `sum([X]*[S])>0`.

Comment: Good idea to reformulate the constraint, +1! For the completeness, `sum([X]*[S]) < 0` should also be taken into account, and then compare and fetch the minimal between solutions under two complementary cases, right?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding To do this inside the model requires a bit of work (e.g. variable splitting). However, I think the `S` parameters are supposed to be positive (from the description).

Comment: Yes, from the description `S` should be non-negative. I purely take the normal-distributed `S` for the completeness purpose. Never mind :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@Erwin Kalvelagen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77685936/12158757), you can reformulate the constraint to make it linear.

---

But, you should be aware of that, the transformation is conditional on `sum([X]*[S])`, that means

- If `sum([X]*[S])>0`, we should have `sum([X]*([C]-payback*[S])) <= 0`
- If `sum([X]*[S])<0`, we should have `sum([X]*([C]-payback*[S])) >= 0`

Then, combine two cases above (compare and take the minimum), we can margin out the impact by `sum([X]*[S])`.

## code example (in `CVXR`)

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 1000 # variable count

# impact
# negative for use in minimization function
I <- -rnorm(n, mean = 20000, sd = 8000)
# cost savings
s <- rnorm(n, mean = 2500, sd = 1000)
# replacement cost
c <- rnorm(n, mean = 15000, sd = 5000)


library(CVXR)
X <- Variable(1, n, boolean = TRUE)
payback_goal <- 3
budget <- 1000000

obj <- Minimize(X %*% I)
# case 1: conditional on X %*% s > 0
constr1 <- list(
  X %*% c <= budget,
  X %*% (c - payback_goal * s) <= 0,
  X %*% s >= 0
)
problem1 <- Problem(obj, constr1)
sol1 <- solve(problem1)

# case 2: conditional on X %*% s < 0
constr2 <- list(
  X %*% c <= budget,
  X %*% (c - payback_goal * s) >= 0,
  X %*% s <= 0
)
problem2 <- Problem(obj, constr2)
sol2 <- solve(problem2)

# compare two cases and take the minimum between them as the solution
if (round(sol1$getValue(X)) %*% I > round(sol2$getValue(X)) %*% I) {
  sol <- sol2
} else {
  sol <- sol1
}
```

and you will see that

```
> round(sol1$getValue(X)) %*% I
         [,1]
[1,] -3064996

> round(sol2$getValue(X)) %*% I
          [,1]
[1,] -287548.7
```

such that `sol` is assigned with `sol1`

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Thank you for clarifying. This is an edge case I didn't consider because I was operating on the assumption that all values of `[s]` would be positive but I can see where this approach may be needed.